# Leaflet.PolylineMeasure doesn't work in new environment

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

We have a project which works with **Leaflet** and **react-leaflet**, also we are using such a great instrument called **Leaflet.PolylineMeasure** for measuring distances.
Main application is based on **babel** and old fashion **React Classes** and works perfectly! 
Recently we've started developing new part of the project using **TypeScript** and functional components with **hooks**.
While working with ruler functionality I had discovered that *Leaflet.PolylineMeasure doesn't work in new environment*! 
According to description of the plugin after adding needed libraries new Measurer function `L.control.polylineMeasure(options)` should appear. But it doesn't!
In main application without TypeScript, hooks, and with the same package version of Leaflet and Leaflet.PolylineMeasure everything still works fine !
I've tried to rewrite map component to **React Class** component, also tried to **add typings** but it does not help.

Any ideas what is the root of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the error because you do not provide any code, however here is how it should look using react typescript, react-leaflet. You can extend the MapControl to implement Leaflet.PolylineMeasure like this:

```
class PolylineMeasure extends MapControl {
  createLeafletElement() {
    return (L.control as any).polylineMeasure({
      position: "topleft",
      unit: "metres",
      showBearings: true,
      clearMeasurementsOnStop: false,
      showClearControl: true,
      showUnitControl: true
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
    const polylineMeasure = this.leafletElement;
    polylineMeasure.addTo(map);
  }
}
```

and then use it inside Map component:

```
const Leaflet = () => {
  return (
    <Map
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      center={[48, 0]}
      zoom={4}
      minZoom={3}
      maxZoom={18}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?"
      />
      <PolylineMeasure />
    </Map>
  );
};
```

You would need to include the following libraries in order not get typescript errors:

1. @types/leaflet
2. @types/react
3. @types/react-dom
4. @types/react-leaflet

For more details check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/leafletpolylinemeasure-doesnt-work-with-hooks-typescript-k80fd)

Comment: It helps! I'm so happy to realize that there's people in the world who are ready to provide quality help (with examples !)
Thank you kboul - you've have solved mine headache